# Picture in two-column beamer break layout (and animation)

Tags: beamer, graphics, two-column

I want to create a LaTeX presentation... my first one.

I have a problem when I want to change the picture/graphics on the right side of the sheet: the distance between the text above the itemize and the itemize change in every follow-up sheet.

When no picture is inserted, everything works fine.

A second problem, probably related to this one, is that the used pictures are moving down. What I mean with moving down is that the distance between the top of the sheet and center of the picture (I think) become greater.

This example works:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}{Example sheet}
    Some text here
    \begin{columns}
        \column{0.5 \textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> A
            \item<2-> B
            \item<3-> C
            \item<4-> D
            \item<5-> E
            \item<6-> F
            \item<7-> G
        \end{itemize}
        \column{0.5 \textwidth}
        % Don't do anything here
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This example doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}{Example sheet}
    Some text here\\
    space between this and first item resize every item
    \begin{columns}
        \column{0.5 \textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> A
            \item<2-> B
            \item<3-> C
            \item<4-> D
            \item<5-> E
            \item<6-> F
            \item<7-> G
        \end{itemize}
        \column{0.5 \textwidth}
        \begin{figure}[t]
            \centering
            \includegraphics<1-1>[width=1\linewidth]{a.png}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{figure}[t]
            \centering
            \includegraphics<2-2>[width=1\linewidth]{b.png}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{figure}[t]
            \centering
            \includegraphics<3-3>[width=1\linewidth]{c.png}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{figure}[t]
            \centering
            \includegraphics<4-4>[width=1\linewidth]{d.png}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{figure}[t]
            \centering
            \includegraphics<5-5>[width=1\linewidth]{e.png}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{figure}[t]
            \centering
            \includegraphics<6-6>[width=1\linewidth]{f.png}
        \end{figure}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

P.S. = This is a non-working example since I don't have a set of pictures I can add. Hence I give my local created results:

[image: Working result without pictures]

The first picture looks like it should looks, except that I need some pictures besides.

[image: Non working version]

The second picture is wrong!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, if this MWE gives what you like to achieve:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example sheet}
    Some text here\\
    space between this and first item resize every item
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \column{0.5 \textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item   A
            \item   B
            \item   C
            \item   D --> A
            \item   E --> B
            \item   F --> C
            \item   G
        \end{itemize}
        \column{0.5 \textwidth}
        \begin{figure}%[ht]
            \centering
            \includegraphics<1>[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \includegraphics<2>[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \includegraphics<3>[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-c}
            \includegraphics<4>[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \includegraphics<5>[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \includegraphics<6>[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-c}
        \end{figure}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

In the list with items `D --> A`, `E --> A`, `F --> A` I wish to indicate, that images, which appears at items `D`, `E` and `F` has letters `A`, `B` and `C` in its center respectively. This indication hasn't any influence on functionality of solution. If you instead of arrow see inverted question mark, means that you use different font encoding (with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` it should appear as `D --> A`).

*Note:* if you uncover `figure` environments, they at each uncover left (invisible) empty figure environment above it. Consequently, new uncover images is placed below it. In proposed solution the environment is only one, placed on the top of of column and in it uncovered images overly previous one.

Comment: What should `D --> A` do? is see after compiling `D -¿ A`.

Comment: @Jan-Bert, intent of the `D --> A` is only to indicate, that image, which appear at item`D` has letter A in its center :) you can simple delete `--> A` or replace altogether with real text. If you see instead of arrow inverted question mark, means that you use different font encoding (with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` it should appear as `D --> A`).

Comment: @Jan-Bert, does answer solve your basic problem?

Comment: Check that explain what i was missing. Yes now it is solved.